# html and php double quote address help? Combine both string into one

Tags: php, html

```
$var = index.html;
```

html code: 
`"http:www.mysite.com/" <?php $var?>`

how to make a html statement which include a php code $var and make it as a string like the following
"http:www.mysite.com/index.html" and read the full address???

Would you guys please give me a quick reply?

*Sorry for posting a bad one here

Comment: `"http:www.mysite.com/<?php echo $var; ?>"`

Comment: I'm happy you at least know you're working with PHP :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you getting through that url? By action attribute in the form or anchor tag?

If you use it in action tag specify the route of the folder then file name.

In anchor tag you need to specify complete url.

You can use

```
<?php $var = "index.html";?>
<a href="<?php echo "http://www.example.com/".$var;?>">Link</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
http://www.mysite.com/<?php echo($var); ?>
```

should do it ... If I understood you

Comment: or use the short tag `<?=$var?>`

Comment: do use them. Even in PHP 5.4 they are always enabled so that is no argument anymore.

Comment: @asprin, I heard that myth too, but `<?=` works even with short open tags disabled (as far as my last test told me). I'd like to know why, because it would reduce my code a lot.

Comment: @WouterH Really? Are you sure it works even with it being disabled in php.ini file?

Comment: @asprin: tested it on my dev machine, and it doesn't work. Anyway I have `<?php print($var); ?>` all over the place, and I really hate this because it leads to errors. `<?=$var?>` would be so much better, so I really would like to know why most of the ppl don't like it. But that's an other discussion.

Comment: @WouterH The only reason could be because in some cases it might be disabled on the hosting server. So it would work on localhost, but spew out errors when hosted live.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for this?

```
<?php echo "http://www.mysite.com/".$var ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php $var = "index.html"; ?>
"http:www.mysite.com/" <?php echo $var; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The dot is a concatenation of strings.

```
$var = "http:www.mysite.com/" . "index.html";
```

---

```
$var = "http:www.mysite.com/";
$var2 = "index.html";
$var = $var . $var2;
```